# Prolog Functions (Ex: Car Ownership History)

Tags: prolog, singleton, chain

**edit:** I figured out the singleton variables. Prolog doesn't like captialized words for data banks. I also made some massive changes to the code.

**edit:edit**: realized I didn't have a recursive call. Derp

I'm pretty new to Prolog though I have some experience in functional programming with Haskell.

Although I am having trouble with trying to make a function output all possible values that make the statement true. I don't think it is a logic error as I have been walking through it for the past few hours but I could be wrong.

In this problem, I am attempting to create the ownership history of a car.

-- I know that a person owns a car IF
        -He/She bought the car from the Dealer
        -He/She bought it from a previous owner of the car.

So knowing these facts I set up a data bank creating cars, owners and a separate variable of dealer which will function as a base case in this recursion.

```
car(prius).
car(bmw).

owner(meg).
owner(nora).
dealer(d).

boughtFrom(meg,nora).
boughtFrom(nora,d).
```

I established that meg bought from nora who bought from the dealer. When you buy from the dealer the recursion I am planning stops as this is the base case end point. 
so the logic goes like this:

```
ownCar(X,Y) :- boughtFrom(X,d), car(Y).
ownCar(X,Y) :- ownCar(boughtFrom(_,prevowner(X)), car(Y)).
```

You can be the owner of the car if you are a dealer or if you bought the car from a previous owner. and that previous owner is the owner if they bought it from either a dealer or another previous owner. etc etc. 
So the only time it stops is when the person bought the car from the dealer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your database is incomplete, because some obvious relation is missing.

This rule, for instance, `ownCar(X,Y) :- boughtFrom(X,d), car(Y).` will be true for *all* Y, i.e anybody bought from dealer will 'own' each car.

The representation is also inaccurate. The seller should not more be the owner after she has sold the car.

Anyway, in Prolog you write *joins* (it's a relational data model), then to get a closure of the transitive property:

```
ownCar(X, Y) :- owner(O), boughtFrom(X, O), ownCar(O, Y).
```

Note that in Prolog we should avoid left recursion, because it could lead to infinite loop, then the order of the join is important.

*edit*

to get the history (as list) you should add an argument to your predicate, or change 'the output'  to be a list. You could do something like

```
ownCar(X, Y, [X]) :- boughtFrom(X,d), car(Y).
ownCar(X, Y, [X|L]) :- owner(O), boughtFrom(X, O), ownCar(O, Y, L).
```

Note: conventionally in Prolog we place 'output' arguments at last argument position.

Comment: Thank you for replying and for your time. 
Okay I understand the recursive issues better. But what I am trying to achieve with the function is to have the names of the previous owners display out.
So when I input `?- ownCar(X, Prius).`
it outputs `X = meg.`
           `X = nora.`
And right now I only get meg because she is the current owner. 
So really I guess the function should be renamed to carOwnerHist